# What does "コマ" mean in this sentence?

Tags: words, food

> お母さん おばあちゃん 今日のカレーは豚コマですよ〜

I looked all over the dictionary for a meaning that matches the context, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Fits perfectly in the context.  https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%B4%B0%E5%88%87%E3%82%8C/#jn-81813

Comment: @l'électeur So, going by your linked dictionary entry, does that mean it's essential *ground pork*?

Comment: Nope, it is (randomly) shredded and/or chopped pork.  It is mostly used for dishes where the meat is NOT the main ingredient.  BTW, we call ground meat ひき肉.　to grind = ひく/挽く

Comment: As far as I know, thinly sliced meat (薄切り肉) or shredded meat (コマ) is not sold in supermarkets in US or Europe. So if you've never been in Japan, it can be hard to imagine. [See this](https://www.kurashiru.com/recipes/19124a50-5b58-4fb1-b66e-5b422e468bd2). Also FYI there is (usually) no 細切れ for chicken.

Comment: @sundowner YUM!  I'm going to have to make that recipe.  Looks amazingly yummy.

Comment: @sundowner Looks like that should be the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the summary of comments.

As l'électeur points out コマ means [細切れ(2)](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%B4%B0%E5%88%87%E3%82%8C/#jn-81813), literally meaning *finely chopped*. 豚コマ is contracted from 豚(の)コマ切れ. The other common コマ is beef: 牛コマ. It is usually cheaper, and (in a non-serious sense) kind of poor man's meat.

As far as I know, コマ肉 is not sold in supermarkets outside Japan, at least not in US or Europe. You can see [this video recipe](https://www.kurashiru.com/recipes/19124a50-5b58-4fb1-b66e-5b422e468bd2) to see what it is like, and [another](https://www.kurashiru.com/recipes/73325e1c-9f81-4db0-8eaa-1c4522324c3e) for the curry with コマ肉.

Generally, コマ肉 is used for stir-fry or stew type of dishes.

===

FYI 薄切り肉(thinly sliced), the other type of cut I mentioned, is commonly used for [Sukiyaki](https://www.kurashiru.com/recipes/6f277fc8-860b-4b19-bde9-0785d48c7194). Preparing this type of meat could be a challenge for making this famous dish abroad (I was once told you should half-freeze a block meat, and then slice it).

Comment: I like the addition of the curry recipe.  I made the pork on last night.  Very good.  I'll have to try to curry tomorrow.  :-)